# Microsoft Edge inicia opacity e transition com bug

Tags: css3, opacity, microsoft-edge

Estou há muito tempo tentando resolver um bug que só ocorre no Microsoft Edge. Preciso criar um link que tenha uma borda em formato de círculo, e dentro deste círculo preciso que tenha uma imagem. Ao passar o mouse, deve surgir uma animação com opacidade na div interna.

Tudo funciona perfeitamente no Chrome e Firefox, porém só no Microsoft Edge que acontece o problema. Ele já inicia como se eu tivesse com o mouse sobre os elementos. Ao que parece, ele está considerando só a opacidade da última div, e não das externas.

O código está neste link: https://jsfiddle.net/fsf4ehsb/1/

Alguém poderia dizer como contornar este problema?

Comment: Melhor adicionar o código na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erro comum na hora de trabalha com o Edge, ele carregou o .ovelayFundo por que ele está livre e sem opacity, e ele não liga pro anterior, a forma de arrumar é assim:

```
.circCategoria .overlay .overlayFundo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  background: #eee808;
  z-index: 5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  /* internet explorer */
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  /* khtml, old safari */
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  /* mozilla, netscape */
  opacity: 0;
  /* fx, safari, opera */
  transition: all 0.5s, background 0.5s;
}

.circCategoria .overlayTexto {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s, background 0.5s;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #01611b;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -30px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  /* internet explorer */
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  /* khtml, old safari */
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  /* mozilla, netscape */
  opacity: 0;
  /* fx, safari, opera */
}

.circCategoria:hover .overlayTexto, .circCategoria .overlay:hover .overlayFundo {
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  /* internet explorer */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
  /* khtml, old safari */
  -moz-opacity: 0.7;
  /* mozilla, netscape */
  opacity: 0.7;
  /* fx, safari, opera */
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rapa09/mv90rvrp/2/

Comment: Perfeito, resolvido o problema! Passei horas tentando resolver. Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda e atenção! Abraços!